# Crystal Reports sort by footer total or only show results from footer total

Tags: sorting, footer

I have a crystal report and I only want to show results that have over 20.  Or, if not possible, I would like to sort descending based on the results.  Are either of these possible?
[image: result]
[image: Report]

I've tried group sort and other options with no results.

Comment: Check out group filters or group selection.

Comment: It won't let me group on a formula field in the footer section.

Comment: What is your formula?

Comment: (Maximum ({RT_METERDROP.Hundreds}, {CDS_SlotMast.SlotNumber})-Minimum ({RT_METERDROP.Hundreds}, {CDS_SlotMast.SlotNumber}))

Comment: You don't need to add a new group. You need to add a condition to the group selection formula or whatever they call it now. There also used to be a way to set up group filters independent of the GSF with an intuitive interface. I've haven't kept up with CR for quite a few years though.

Comment: "Group Sort Expert" may be what I'm thinking of. Personally I think I'd try the selection formula first.